# How to access files on IBM's Cloud Object Storage via RESTful

Tags: restful-url, ibm-cloud-storage, klipfolio

I want to expose/share CSV files on IBM's Cloud Object Storage (COS) to an external service (Klipfolio) using a RESTful access. At this moment, I do not understand how to properly set up the URL for that RESTful access (or whether is it possible at all to access COS files via RESTful).

On IBMs Cloud I have:
- created a COS service with its credentials, and
- created a bucket, and 
- uploaded a test file to that bucket

I have read up and down documentations both on IBM and the other app (Klipfolio) but still clueless on how to set up that RESTful access to COS files. This is my first time with RESTful, so I am certainly a bit confused.

I am including an attachment of what Klipfolio is expecting (a URL and the credentials), therefore this is not about creating any code to download the file, but rather just directly accessing it via a URL.

Any help/hint will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Manuel

[image: Screenshot of Klipfolio form to import/query a file]

Answer (score 1):

COS uses an [API key to authenticate](https://www.bluemix.net/iam/#/apikeys) and once this is obtained you can create an API call with the REST/URL connector in Klipfolio. Pass the API key in a header within the query parameters section of the REST/URL connector. Here is an example call to list the buckets. Replace everything in {} with your specific values.

Query URL: https://{endpoint}/

Query Parameters:

1.
Name: Authorization /
Value: Bearer {api key} /
Type: Header

2. Name: ibm-service-instance-id /
   Value: {resource-instance-id} /
   Type: Header

[image: Example COS List Buckets API call]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access COS buckets and objects through a REST API.

It looks like the information Klipfolio app is looking for is similar to
the COS API Postman examples here
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/api-reference/postman.html#using-postman-

For reference here is an overview of the COS API
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/api-reference/about-api.html#about-the-ibm-cloud-object-storage-api

Mike